# INNER JOIN Syntax

Tags: c#, sql

Hows does the inner join Syntax work? I'm new to SQL and i really dont understand how INNER JOIN works

```
queryString = @"SELECT * from WGCDOCCAB
               WHERE serie ='1' AND tipodoc ='FSS' AND contribuinte ='999999990' AND numdoc = 
               INNER JOIN  wgcnumeradores on wgcdoccab.numdoc = wgcnumerador.numero";
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong, im sure its the syntax, im using C# Visual Studio 2013 and MySQl

Comment: Your 'inner join' clause must be placed before your 'where' clause

Comment: `AND numdoc = INNER JOIN` looks weird..

Comment: This is trivially Google-able, and extensively covered in the documentation:  https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+join+syntax&oq=mysql+join+syntax.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner join is used when you are pulling related data out of more than one table. As pointed out above, INNER JOIN comes before WHERE clause. try this:

```
queryString = @"SELECT * from WGCDOCCAB
INNER JOIN  wgcnumeradores on wgcdoccab.numdoc = wgcnumerador.numero
           WHERE serie ='1' AND tipodoc ='FSS' AND contribuinte ='999999990'";
```

Here is an explanation for the inner join:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190014(v=SQL.105).aspx